# Compress output of Gdal.Grid in Python

Tags: python, gdal

How can I specify compression in Python Gdal.Grid? Currently, I do not see [an option](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Grid) to specify compression while performing `gdal.Grid` operation.

```
gdal.Grid(output_raster_path, geodata,
                    zfield=field,
                    algorithm="linear",
                    outputBounds=[ulx, uly, lrx, lry],
                    width=xsize, height=ysize)
```

To perform compression, I'm currently calling gdal translate on the result of `gdal.Grid` operation.

```
ds = gdal.Translate(output_file, input_file, creationOptions=["COMPRESS=LZW", "TILED=YES"])
ds = None
```

Comment: https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.GridOptions suggests that a list of creation options can be passed passed via the `creationOptions` kwarg, just like you're doing with `gdal.Translate`.  Is that not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like `gdal.Translate`, `gdal.Grid` accepts [creationOptions](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.GridOptions):

```
gdal.Grid(output_raster_path, geodata,
          zfield=field,
          algorithm="linear",
          outputBounds=[ulx, uly, lrx, lry],
          width=xsize, height=ysize, 
          creationOptions=["COMPRESS=LZW", "TILED=YES"])
```